# Examples of abnormal sets

Tags: set-theory, paradoxes

If a set is a member of itself, then it is called an Abnormal set. One such example would be: Let `S` be a set such that `S` contains all sets. Then `S` itself is a member of `S`. Is this the only example of an abnormal set? Are there other sets that are abnormal?

Comment: What set theory are you working with?  Under $\mathsf{ZFC}$, no such sets can exist.

Comment: Treatments of set theory often include an axiom (Mirimanoff's) designed to prohibit "abnormal" sets. In the absence of such an axiom, the equation $x=\{x\}$ could have a vast number of solutions.